# seletor de plano que mostra valor em outro imput

Tags: javascript, html-select

```js
//função exibe data de hoje no campo cancelamento

    var dia, mes,ano;

    function Data(){
        data = new Date();
        dia = data.getDate();
        mes = data.getMonth()+1;
        ano = data.getFullYear();
            if (dia <10){
          dia ='0'+dia;
        }
        if (mes <10){
          mes ='0'+mes; 
        }
        dataCompleta = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

        return dataCompleta;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        //formato para calculo
        document.getElementById("cancelamento").value = Data();
        //formato para visualização
        document.getElementById("visualiza").value = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;; 
    }

/*função calcula a data com base nos inputs adesão e cancelamento e deve retornar a diverença entre eles em meses*/
    function calculaData(){
        var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
        var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);

        var timeDiff = Math.abs(cancelamento.getTime() - adesao.getTime());
        //retorno em dias
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30)); 
        document.getElementById("tempo").value = diffDays;
    }

/*função calcula a data com base nos inputs adesão e cancelamento e deve retornar a diverença entre eles em meses*/
    function calculaData(){
        var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
        var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);

        var timeDiff = Math.abs(cancelamento.getTime() - adesao.getTime());
        //retorno em dias
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30)); 
       document.getElementById("tempo").value = diffDays;
     }
     //Transferir valor do campo plano para o campo individual
$('#seletor').change(function() {
var valor = $('#seletor').val();
$('#individual').val(valor);
});

        function calculaParcela(){
       var individual = parseFloat(document.retencao.individual.value);
     var dependente = parseFloat(document.retencao.dependente.value);
       var parcela = individual * dependente;
       document.getElementById("parcela").value = parcela.toFixed(2) ; 
       }
       
       function calculaInvestimento(){
     var vparcela = parseFloat(document.retencao.parcela.value);
     
     var tempo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tempo").value);
     
     var investimento = vparcela * tempo;
     document.getElementById("investimento").value = investimento.toFixed(2) ;           
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title> Retenção </title>
<script language="javascript" src="javascript/funcoes.js">  </script>
<!-- Importar biblioteca jQuery (biblioteca JavaScript) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
  <body>
<form name="retencao">
<fieldset>
<legend >Calculo de Investimento</legend>
<label>Adesão</label>
<input type="date" id="adesao" name="adesao" required="required" onchange="calculaData()">  
<!--pega a data de adesão do beneficiario-->    
<label>Cancelamento</label>
<!--data do cancelamento simples visualizaçao-->
<input style="display:none" type="text" id="cancelamento" name="cancelamento" onload="calculaData()">
<!--data de cancelamento do beneficiario pega a data atual-->
<input type="text" id="visualiza" name="visualiza" readonly="readonly" size="8">
<label>Planos</label>
<select id="seletor" required="required" name="seletor" onchange="calculaParcela()">
<!--Para o seletor de planos pensei em um imput select, com a seleção do plano por esse imput preciso 
que o valor seja retornado no imput individual-->
<option selected="selected" value="">Selecione o plano</option>
<option value="29.90">Fundamental</option>  
<option value="36.90">Vital</option>
</select>
<label>Dependentes</label>
<!--Aqui sera informado a quantidade de beneficiarios para calculo no valor da  parcela-->
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" id="depedente" name="dependente" required="required" onchange="calculaParcela()">
<br>        
<label>Tempo de plano</label>
<!--Este imput deve receber o resultado de uma conta dos campos adesão e cancelamento da seguinte
forma =cancelmamento - adesão e retornar a quantidade de meses que o beneficiario permaneceu com o 
plano -->
<input type="text" name="tempo" id="tempo" size="10"readonly="readonly" >
<label>Individual</label>
<!--Recebe valor artibuido ao select com o valor do plano-->
<input type="text" id="individual" name="individual" size="10">    
<label>Parcela</label>
<!--Parcela recebe a quantidade de dependentes vezes o valor individual-->
<input type="text" name="parcela" id="parcela" size="10" readonly="readonly" >
<label>Investimento</label>
<!--Investimento deve mutiplicar a quantidade de meses vezes o valor da parcela para retorno do valor
investido durante o tempo que o beneficiario permaneceu com o plano-->
<input type="text" name="investimento" id="investimento" readonly="readonly" size="10">
<br>
<input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="calculaInvestimento()">      
</fieldset>     
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um seletor de plano com o campo de id=seletor de forma que ele transfira o valor do plano para o campo Individual sempre que o mesmo for alterado até agora o programa já esta quase no final graças a contribuição de muitos de vocês mais dei uma procurada na internet e não achei nada semelhante ao que quero fazer alguém tem alguma ideia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria isso que você queria fazer?

```js
//função exibe data de hoje no campo cancelamento

        var dia, mes,ano;

        function Data(){
            data = new Date();
            dia = data.getDate();
            mes = data.getMonth()+1;
            ano = data.getFullYear();
                if (dia <10){
              dia ='0'+dia;
            }
            if (mes <10){
              mes ='0'+mes; 
            }
            dataCompleta = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

            return dataCompleta;
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            //formato para calculo
            document.getElementById("cancelamento").value = Data();
            //formato para visualização
            document.getElementById("visualiza").value = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;; 
        }

    /*função calcula a data com base nos inputs adesão e cancelamento e deve retornar a diverença entre eles em meses*/
        function calculaData(){
            var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
            var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(cancelamento.getTime() - adesao.getTime());
            //retorno em dias
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30)); 
            document.getElementById("tempo").value = diffDays;
        }

    /*função calcula a data com base nos inputs adesão e cancelamento e deve retornar a diverença entre eles em meses*/
        function calculaData(){
            var adesao = new Date (document.retencao.adesao.value);
            var cancelamento = new Date (document.retencao.cancelamento.value);

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(cancelamento.getTime() - adesao.getTime());
            //retorno em dias
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30)); 
           document.getElementById("tempo").value = diffDays;
         }
            function calculaParcela(){
           var individual = parseFloat(document.retencao.individual.value);
           var dependente = parseFloat(document.retencao.dependente.value);
           var parcela = individual * dependente;
           document.getElementById("parcela").value = parcela.toFixed(2) ; 
           }
           
           function calculaInvestimento(){
     var vparcela = parseFloat(document.retencao.parcela.value);
     
     var tempo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tempo").value);
     
     var investimento = vparcela * tempo;
     document.getElementById("investimento").value = investimento.toFixed(2) ;           
           }
     
//Transferir valor do campo plano para o campo individual
$('#seletor').change(function() {
    var valor = $('#seletor').val();
    $('#individual').val(valor);
});
```

```html
<!-- Importar biblioteca jQuery (biblioteca JavaScript) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title> Retenção </title>
    <script language="javascript" src="javascript/funcoes.js">  </script> 
</head>
  <body>
<form name="retencao">
    <fieldset>
    <legend >Calculo de Investimento</legend>
    <label>Adesão</label>
    <input type="date" id="adesao" name="adesao" required="required" onchange="calculaData()">  
    <!--pega a data de adesão do beneficiario-->    
    <label>Cancelamento</label>
    <!--data do cancelamento simples visualizaçao-->
    <input style="display:none" type="text" id="cancelamento" name="cancelamento" onload="calculaData()">
    <!--data de cancelamento do beneficiario pega a data atual-->
    <input type="text" id="visualiza" name="visualiza" readonly="readonly" size="8">
    <label>Planos</label>
    <select id="seletor" required="required" name="seletor">
    <!--Para o seletor de planos pensei em um imput select, com a seleção do plano por esse imput preciso 
    que o valor seja retornado no imput individual-->
    <option selected="selected" value="">Selecione o plano</option>
    <option value="29.90">Fundamental</option>      
    </select>
    <label>Dependentes</label>
    <!--Aqui sera informado a quantidade de beneficiarios para calculo no valor da  parcela-->
    <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" id="depedente" name="dependente" required="required" onchange="calculaParcela()">
    <br>        
    <label>Tempo de plano</label>
    <!--Este imput deve receber o resultado de uma conta dos campos adesão e cancelamento da seguinte
    forma =cancelmamento - adesão e retornar a quantidade de meses que o beneficiario permaneceu com o 
    plano -->
    <input type="text" name="tempo" id="tempo" size="10"readonly="readonly" >
    <label>Individual</label>
    <!--Recebe valor artibuido ao select com o valor do plano-->
    <input type="text" id="individual" name="individual" size="10" oninput="calculaParcela()" >    
    <label>Parcela</label>
    <!--Parcela recebe a quantidade de dependentes vezes o valor individual-->
    <input type="text" name="parcela" id="parcela" size="10" readonly="readonly" >
    <label>Investimento</label>
    <!--Investimento deve mutiplicar a quantidade de meses vezes o valor da parcela para retorno do valor
    investido durante o tempo que o beneficiario permaneceu com o plano-->
    <input type="text" name="investimento" id="investimento" readonly="readonly" size="10">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="calculaInvestimento()">      
    </fieldset>     
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não na verdade não eu coloquei o no select plano, um valor 29.90, preciso de uma função que imprima o valor de um plano toda vez que eu mudar no select no campo individual

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron Poderia explicar melhor qual o comportamento desejado? Na pergunta você falou que gostaria que ele transfira o valor do plano para o campo Individual sempre que o mesmo for alterado.

Comment: o meu código tem um select que tem o plano fundamental certo o valor dele é de 29.90 gostaria que ao selecionar ele o valor de 29.90 fosse exibido  no campo individual entendeu

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron Isso já está ocorrendo, faça o teste no código que postei acima. Clique no botão 'executar' na minha resposta e selecione a opção ''Fundamental' no campo, o valor em questão 29,90 aparecerá no campo 'individual'.

Comment: era isso mesmo valeu, muito obrigado

Comment: Masa, fico feliz em ter ajudado, depois só aceita a resposta, por favor, para indicar para a comunidade que a pergunta em questão já foi respondida e o problema solucionado.

Comment: como faço @LeandroSilva

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron Basta clicar no sinal de correto (parece um 'V') ao lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: cara eu testei o codigo copiei exatamente o seu o Jquery num ta funcionando não aqui funcionou normal e funciona e ai tentei abrir no navegador num ta funcionando tem algum debuguer bom?

Comment: @RafaelDiasZendron Você copiou o script jQuery e importou a biblioteca jQuery dentro da tag head da página? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ? Lembrando que, para que tal código funcione, como a biblioteca está em um site externo é necessário que o computador em que você está testando esteja conectado a internet.

Comment: @LeeandroSilva ja tentei baixando jquery e com ele aparfir do cdn google pelo debug do navegador aparece a biblioteca jquery so q num ta rodando o script, tinha tido problema com o $ tudo q coloquei a linha da biblioteca antes do funcoes.js reconheceu $ meu codigo ta igual ao seu acima com as edicoes e funcao q vc sugeriu testando no navegador nada de funcionar, vou editar minha pergunta e postar como ficou apos suas sugestoes logo mais

Comment: @LeandronSilva o código na minha pergunta agora sim já esta igual ao seu só que ele só funciona quando executado aqui quando executado diretamente no navegador não esta rodando alguma sugestão

Comment: o codigo proposto em jquery no navegador roda antes do fechamento da tag </body> mas anula os cálculos de parcela impedindo o investimento o ideal seria como editei acima que roda  os cálculos mas no navegador ele ignora o jquery